# Bitwise error in <linux/jiffies.h>

Tags: c, linux, gcc

So I succeeded into getting the header  to almost compile(got rid of that division by zero error)but there is 1 troublesome bug in 4 lines of the header code that stubbornly refuses to be resolved. Here it is below. The compiler error I keep getting is: *error: missing binary operator before token "("*. And it points directly to the line with the "#if" preprocessor conditional expression.

```
#define SEC_JIFFIE_SC (31 - SHIFT_HZ)
#if !((((NSEC_PER_SEC << 2) / TICK_NSEC) << (SEC_JIFFIE_SC - 2)) & 0x80000000)
#undef SEC_JIFFIE_SC
#define SEC_JIFFIE_SC (32 - SHIFT_HZ)
#endif
```

That "!" is supposed to be a bitwise not I think and using "~" instead doesn't help.

Comment: Almost certainly one of the macros `NSEC_PER_SEC`, `TICK_NSEC` or `SHIFT_HZ` isn't defined when this code is encountered.

Comment: It might be NSEC_PER_SEC since TICK_NSEC is defined as a function of the former and SHIFT_HZ is defined in another header included in <linux/jiffies.h>. Thanks!

Comment: What about looking at the pre-processor's output? To do so run `cpp somefilename.c`